# MathJax text displayed all in one line

Tags: mathjax, anki

I like to use MathJax in Anki. It gives great aesthetic pleasure :)

However, when I write a something a bit longer using:

`\(\text{...}\)`

Anki displays it all in one line.
How to make it adapt to the window size?

Alternatively, and preferably, how do I change the styling (shared between cards) to resemble the MathJax style?

---

Linux

Answer (score 1):

Solved by changing the Styling (shared between the card) to:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MJX_Main';
  src: url('http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/eot/MathJax_Main-Regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/eot/MathJax_Main-Regular.eot?iefix') format('eot'),
       url('http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/woff/MathJax_Main-Regular.woff')  format('woff'),
       url('http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/otf/MathJax_Main-Regular.otf')  format('opentype'),
       url('http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/svg/MathJax_Main-Regular.svg#MathJax_Main-Regular') format('svg');
}

.card {
 font-family: MJX_Main;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 color: black;
 background-color: white;
}
```